# piecewise differential equations solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms, piecewise-continuity, programming

I have to solve the exact solutions of the following piece-wise differential equations.
$$x''+0.4x'+x=1\ (x'>2.5)$$
$$x''+0.4x'+x=-1\ (x'<-2.5)$$
$$x''-0.4x'+x=0\ (-2.5<x'<2.5)$$
$$x(0)=0.1,\ x'(0)=0.0$$
The phase plot of the solutions is expected to be like the image below.

[Euler Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHmHh.png)

The above phase plot is generated by Euler methods and is proved to be the right answer. However, when finding the exact solutions using the below C program, the result is not like the image above. With the decided initial conditions, it begins with the third equation.When time reaches 17.1s (when $x'$ reaches boundary) it jumps to the first equations but the solution $x'$ it generated immediately return it to the third equation which is not continuous like the image.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DT 20
#define T DT*1000
#define del 0.2
#define del2 0.2
#define omega1 sqrt(1-del*del)
#define omega2 sqrt(1-del2*del2)
#define Th 2.5
void main(void)
{
FILE *fp;
int i;
\\define the initial conditions x(0)=0.1, x'(0)=y(0)=0, h=0.05
double x = 0.1, t = 0.0, h = 1.0 / DT, y = 0.0,x0,y0; 

fp = fopen("Kai.csv", "w+");
fprintf(fp, "tau, x, x'\n");


for (i = 0; i <= T; i++) {
x0 = x; \\ Save the new initial conditions for using when x' reach the boundary
y0 = y;
if (y > Th) {
    while (y > Th) {
        \\Solution for x, x' with initial conditions x0, y0
        x = exp(-del*t)*((x0 - 1)*cos(omega1*t) + (1 / omega1)*(y0 + del*(x0 - 1))*sin(omega1*t)) + 1; 
        y = exp(-del*t)*(y0*cos(omega1*t) - (1 / omega1)*(del*y0 + (x0 - 1))*sin(omega1*t));
        fprintf(fp, "%f, %f,%f\n", t, x, y);
        t = t + h;
    }
}
else if (y < -Th) {
    while (y < -Th) {
        x = exp(-del*t)*((x0 + 1)*cos(omega1*t) + (1 / omega1)*(y0 + del*(x0 + 1))*sin(omega1*t)) - 1;
        y = exp(-del*t)*(y0*cos(omega1*t) - (1 / omega1)*(del*y0 + (x0 + 1))*sin(omega1*t));
        fprintf(fp, "%f, %f,%f\n", t, x, y);
        t = t + h;
    }
}
else {
    while ((y>=-Th) && (y<=Th)) {
        x = exp(del2*t)*(x0*cos(omega2*t) + (1 / omega2)*(y0 - del2*x0)*sin(omega2*t));
        y = exp(del2*t)*(y0*cos(omega2*t) + (1 / omega2)*(del2*y0 - x0)*sin(omega2*t));
        fprintf(fp, "%f, %f,%f\n", t, x, y);
        t = t + h;
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

I can't find what is the problem with my code.
Please show me where I went wrong in this code. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Euler method is bound to diverge, sometimes slowly, sometimes more abruptly. This may be a part of the explanation...

Comment: My lecturer said something about connecting the solutions but I don't really understand what connecting could possibly mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your propagator formulas for $x''+2\delta x'+x=f$, $ω=\sqrt{1-δ^2}$, for the values at $t=t_0+Δt$ should be 
\begin{align}
x(t)&=f+e^{-δ\,Δt}\Bigl((x_0-f)·\cos(ω\,Δt)+\frac1ω(y_0 + δ·(x_0 - f))·\sin(ω\,Δt)\Bigr)
\\
y(t)&=e^{-δ\, Δt}\Bigl(y_0·\cos(ω\, Δt) - \frac1ω(δ·y_0 + (x_0 - f))·\sin(ω\, Δt)\Bigr)
\end{align}
where $x_0=x(t_0)$ and $y_0=y(t_0)$ are the values at the last step. This is largely correct in your code, but you are using $t$ instead of the time increment $Δt=t-t_0$ leading to the observed jumps at the first change of the cases.

Easy test: for $Δt=0$ the formulas should reproduce the values $x_0,y_0$, which they do.

After correcting the code by introducing `t0` along `x0,y0` and using `(t-t0)` in the formulas, the solution is indeed spiralling outwards towards a, not exactly circular, limit cycle.